# Angular + Node + Express + Passport + oauth2orize unique CORS issues

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, oauth2orize

I've built an API to use for local auth and Facebook auth.

I'm using **node**, **express**, **passport** and **oauth2orize** for the authorization process.

I'm now running the API perfectly through terminal applications and API testing suites, however, when making calls to my authentication endpoints from angular I receive the following:

**Local auth:**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

http://localhost:4200/oauth2/auth
    ?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]
    &redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:4200%2Foauth2%2Fauth%2Fcallback (http://localhost:4200/oauth2/auth/callback)
    &response_type=code.

This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

**Facebook auth:**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    ?response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback (http://localhost/auth/facebook/callback)
    &client_id=[CLIENT_ID].

This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I have had CORS issues in the past and integrated the *npm* '**cors**' middleware module found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

**CORS init:**

```
var cors = require('cors');
api.use(cors());
```

With my previous issues, this was sufficient, however, with these new CORS issues it's not helping.

I've also noticed, in Firefox, if I click on the error message, a new dialog window opens up as it should and the server continues to correctly authorize the user.

Could anyone help?

***UPDATE 1:***

Check comments for screenshot of debug info.

***UPDATE 2:***

Response headers for the last 2 requests performed in the login flow.

1. **204:**

   ```
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Connection: keep-alive
   Date: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 15:26:43 GMT
   Vary: Origin
   X-Powered-By: Express
   access-control-allow-headers: authorization
   access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
   access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8100
   ```
2. **302:**

   ```
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Length: 138
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
   Date: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 15:26:43 GMT
   Location: http://localhost:4200/oauth2/auth/callback?code=[CODE_HERE]
   Set-Cookie: connect.sid=[SID_HERE]; Path=/; HttpOnly
   Vary: Origin, Accept
   X-Powered-By: Express
   access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8100
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The earlier examples in the docs don't include handling the preflight request, and do not specify any origins, which is required if you want to send any credentials with the requests (for example, your authorization header). Here's an example:

```
var whitelist = ['https://localhost:4200']; // Acceptable domain names. ie: https://www.example.com
var corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
    // callback(null, true); uncomment this and comment the above to allow all
  }
};

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
// Enable CORS Pre-Flight
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Hmm, this still isn't working, I've tried both using the whitelist array and using the 'allow all' option but it's still returning the same errors that I originally posted.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it Kevin, here is a snapshot of my network debug tab and the logged error from the start of my login process to the end.

http://i.imgur.com/nRbdMiG.png

Comment: Can you list the headers returned from the last two requests? add it in a code section within your question.